# Accessing multiple folder matlab and store in same mat

Tags: matlab

I am newbie to Matlab. I have code like below. How to read multiple folder. I know by using loop but somehow I google it I cannot find it. Also,what i have wrote below is for myA folder. How to put featureVector in same mat AllTrain for myA, myB, myC? The folder contain of image.

```
clear all; 
clc; 

trainlabel = [];
featureVector = [];
AllTrain = [];

% Specify the folder 
myA = 'C:\Users\NotComplex\a';
myB = 'C:\Users\NotComplex\b'; 
myC = 'C:\Users\NotComplex\c'; 

for k = 1 : length(theFiles)
 baseFileName = theFiles(k).name;
 fullFileName = fullfile(myA, baseFileName);
 fprintf(1, 'Now reading %s\n', fullFileName);
 % Now imread the file
 imageArray = imread(fullFileName);
 imageEdge = edge(imageArray, 'canny', 0.4);

 a_inv_mom = Hu_Moments(imageEdge);
 format short
 a_inv_mom_normal = -sign(a_inv_mom).*(log10(abs(a_inv_mom)));

 featureVector = cat(1,a_inv_mom_normal);
 AllTrain(k,:) = [featureVector k];

 % imshow(imageEdge);  % Display image.
 drawnow % Force display to update immediately.
end
```

Comment: If you expect some help:
what is the content of `theFiles`?

Comment: Maybe your question is duplicate. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11980192/matlab-multiple-folders?rq=1

Comment: filePattern = fullfile(myA, '*.pgm'); theFiles = dir(filePattern); I forgot to paste the code. sorry. @DVarga.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To be compact:**

```
folderCell = {'C:\Users\NotComplex\a', 'C:\Users\NotComplex\b', 'C:\Users\NotComplex\c'};

theFiles = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(x, '*.pgm'), folderCell, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Then you can continue with your loop, `theFiles` will contain all of the `.pgm` files from all of the three directories